# How can I solve "Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind"?

Tags: git, github, version-control, push, atlassian-sourcetree

I want to push to github. I am using SourceTree.

When I push, I get an error like this:

[image: error]

How can I solve this problem?

The graph on SourceTree is like this:

[image: graph]

If I pull, it displays an error too like this:

[image: pull]

Comment: Did you do a Pull first?

Comment: @jdoer1997 I update my question. If I pull, there exist error

Comment: We appreciate your question updates, but images of text are pretty heavily frowned upon. Take a moment to make it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

In your screen shot you can see 3 commits, two commits are connected, test and remove test, but then your newest commit does not have a parent, hence no related histories.

#### Option 1 ( `origin/master` has no useful code)

Judging by the commit messages, you have an empty repo before your latest commit. In this situation, I would force replace what is on remote by doing `git push -f`.

**Please note** this will delete the commits labeled `test` and `remove test`.

#### Option 2 ( Keep `origin/master`)

Use `git cherry-pick` those commits into your local master. Always do this oldest to newest.

```
git cherry-pick <commit hash>
```

Comment: `git push -f`. How can I do it in sourcetree? And i'm still confused about option 2

Comment: @happyforever According to [this link](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/How-do-I-perform-a-forced-push-push-f-from-SourceTree/qaq-p/257351) force push is not exposed in source tree, you'll need to use the command line. For Option 2 [this link](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/SourceTree-How-do-I-cherry-pick/qaq-p/376760) Explains cherry picking in source tree.